# Why does jQuery create global variable $ if it's AMD compliant?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm new to AMD and loaders like require.js, but so far I've been under the assumption that a properly structured require.js project does not create any global variables. How come a script like jQuery can be loaded via require.js and appear to be AMD-compliant, but it still creates a global `$` variable?

Am I misunderstanding what AMD compliant means or how it works? I'm looking into writing my own AMD-compliant modules but I want to make sure I'm doing things the proper way...

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        "jquery": "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min"
    }
});

require(["jquery"], function(jquery) {
    console.log(jquery);
    console.log($); // This works, but I wouldn't expect it to.
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery creates the global `$` variable because JQuery is not designed to be an AMD module, although it does support it.  You can wrap JQuery to remove the global `$` scope as described [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#cdnconfig), if you read the section on JQuery it explains the reasons why the global variable is there.  I remember doing this when I first started using requirejs but it caused some problems with plugins ... as I remember